# Bing Map REST API is not working

Tags: rest, bing-maps

if i place the below URL in my browser 
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q=bangalore+karnataka+india&key=

The response is below

```
    {
authenticationResultCode: "ValidCredentials",
brandLogoUri: "http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png",
copyright: "Copyright Â© 2014 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
resourceSets: [
{
estimatedTotal: 0,
resources: [ ]
}
],
statusCode: 200,
statusDescription: "OK",
traceId: "f54d507047604f1585db1e00254b9a7d|SINM000007|02.00.183.2300|SINMSNVM000034"
}
```

Not getting the **resources**

Any issue in the URL?

Comment: Looks strange the URL works with my key/credentials though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate limiting is a possibility, however I believe your issue is with your query. Spaces should be encoded as %20 and not a +. Try this query instead: http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q=bangalore%20karnataka%20india&key=YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY

Also, take a look at these tips and tricks for the REST services: http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/02/14/bing-maps-rest-service-tips-amp-tricks.aspx

Comment: You shouldn't get no results for the URL I provided (assuming you added your Bing Maps key to it). Are you able to get any other queries to work? Try London.

Answer (score 1):

Empty results are returned when your account is rate limited. Note that all Basic and Trial keys are subject to rate limiting as documented in the terms of use.

Comment: where i can find this information? how can i increase this rate?

Comment: You would need to switch to enterprise key. :)